# How can I get my dapp interface to work on Mist? I'm using truffle framework and it works with Metamask

Tags: web3js, mist, truffle, dapp-development

I can't get my interface to work on Mist using truffle contract abstraction.
After building and testing successfully with Metamask I thought I'd test it on Mist as well and, surprise, it doesn't work. I did some digging and "cut down some trees" to see where the problem is and concluded there is a conflict when using web3.eth.filter and MyContract.deployed() together.

I would be grateful if someone could test the following code to see I'm not the only one with the problem. My setup is truffle v3.4.7 + geth v1.6.6 with rpc.

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {

    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    var filter = web3.eth.filter("latest");
    filter.watch(function(error, result) {
        if (error != null) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        console.log('new block');
    });

    MyContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
    MyContract.deployed().then(function (value) {
        console.log('contract found!');
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

}
```

The above gives this error:

```
Error: MyContract has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
```

Did some digging on this and it appears that network_id gets corrupted for a while with some random value like "0x6197b6fe01d72d08b3ddfce26f9fe409" before it takes the right value, like "4" (Rinkeby).

I ended up finding that invoking web3.version.getNetwork before all the code above takes care of this problem but many other errors take its place. I think went a little to far trying to find workarounds for days and I need your help in solving this the right way. Can you think of anything? Thanks.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same problem. The workaround to call web3.version.getNetWork before trying to access deployed contracts seems to work fine here, but obviously thats just ugly. If you found a real solution in the meantime, please update the question. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I stopped using truffle and all the problems went away. I tried getting help on their gitter channel as well but nobody responded. And now that I know how to work without truffle I don't even find it as useful as I did.